# is Minkowski distance is the $L^p$ norm of the distance between two points?

Tags: vector-spaces, machine-learning

The [Minkowski distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_distance) of order p between two points

$${\displaystyle X=(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots ,x_{n}){\text{ and }}Y=(y_{1},y_{2},\ldots ,y_{n})\in \mathbb {R} ^{n}}$$

is defined as:

$${\displaystyle D\left(X,Y\right)=\left(\sum _{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}-y_{i}|^{p}\right)^{1/p}}$$

For a real number p ≥ 1, the [p-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions) or $L^p$-norm of x is defined by

$${\displaystyle \left\|x\right\|_{p}=\left(|x_{1}|^{p}+|x_{2}|^{p}+\dotsb +|x_{n}|^{p}\right)^{1/p}.}$$

it seems that the Minkowski distance is the $L^p$ norm of the distance between two points.

is my understanding right?

Comment: Norm of the difference, you mean. Whenever you have a norm $\|\cdot\|$ then $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$ is a distance, so yes.

Comment: Distance between two points is supposed to be a non-negative real number, so it does not make sense to say $L_p$ norm of “distance between two points.” However, since you are in a vector space $X-Y$ is a bonafide point in your vector space, and the Minkowsko distance is the norm of this vector.